# Can not install gem on window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

When I run command: gem bundle install 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' the result is:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.10.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.10.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing therubyracer (0.10.1), and Bundler cannot continue
```

Who can tell me what wrong?

Comment: It failed to build the gem native extension.....But seriously, we need some more information. It should have printed out a lot of confusing lines above that saying something about errors and warnings and such. Could you post those? (Your entire console print out)

Answer (score 1):

That one doesn't work on windows. There is a 'static branch' of (twitter-bootstrap-rails) if I recall correctly that does, but it will cause you lots of headaches. Rails performance on windows is extremely poor anyway, so I recommend you find a linux host.